# Extrude convex hull

Tags: matlab, convex-hull, point-clouds

Hy!

I have a set of points in 3d which all lie on a plane and represent the floor of a room.
Now I want to create walls. My idea is to extrude the floor, or to use translational sweeps.
I tried to finds some code in the web or information where to start, but I wasn't lucky.

Does anyone now some good tutorials or libs?
THX

Comment: How does this relates to matlab ?

Comment: For a question on Stack Overflow it is expected that you provide a clear description of what you want to achieve, describe your own attempts to answer the question, and state exactly where you got stuck. Moreover, most of the time it increases the chances for a good answer if you include a *small* piece of (non-) working code (possibly including data).